# add data sources to blaze server

Tags: python, blaze

I want to run a blaze server which mounts two data sources, one postgreSQL table and one CSV file, but I dont know how can I mount more than one data source on blaze server.

I have the following code on server side:

```
engine = create_engine('postgresql://user:pass@localhost:5432/mydb')
with engine.connect() as conn:
    metadata=MetaData()
    metadata.bind=engine
    t=Table('t', metadata, autoload=True, autoload_with=conn)

server=bz.Server(t)
server.run(host='0.0.0.0', port=6363)
```

and in the client side:

```
source =Data('blaze://localhost:6363/')
t=symbol('t', source.dshape)
expr=t[t.color=='K']
result=compute(expr, Data(source))
```

how can I mount another data source like CSV file or another table of the database on the same blaze server?
 for example:

```
csv= Data('.\data.csv', sep=';', has_header=True)
```

**Update:**

I had to add the data sources as dictionary to my server,

```
engine = create_engine('postgresql://qfsa:123@localhost:5433/mydb')
with engine.connect() as conn:
    metadata=MetaData()
    metadata.bind=engine
    table1=Data(Table('tablename1', metadata, autoload=True, autoload_with=conn))
    table2=Data(Table('tablename2', metadata, autoload=True, autoload_with=conn)
csvfile=Data('.\data.csv', sep=';', has_header=True)
resources={
        'table1': table1,
        'table2': table2,
        'csvfile': csvfile
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I got the answer to this question from here:

https://github.com/blaze/blaze/issues/1631

The standard way to do this would be to make the server's resource a dictionary of other resources. I updated the question.